# pandas dataframe split and get last element of list

Tags: python, pandas, list, split, element

I have a pandas dataframe and in one column I have a string where words are separated by '_', I would like to extract the last element of this string (which is a number) and make a new column with this.
I tried the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['some_string_25','a_different_one_13','and_a_last_one_40']})
df.assign(number = lambda x: x.strings.str.split('_')[0])
```

but it gives me this in my last column

```
number
some
string
25
```

but I would like to get this

```
number
25
13
40
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for split and select last value of list by indexing or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by last integer of strings - `(\d+)` is for match int and `$` for end of string:

```
df['last'] = df['strings'].str.split('_').str[-1]
df['last1'] = df['strings'].str.extract('(\d+)$')

print (df)
              strings last last1
0      some_string_25   25    25
1  a_different_one_13   13    13
2   and_a_last_one_40   40    40
```

Difference is possible see in changed data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['some_string_25','a_different_one_13','and_a_last_one_40', 
                              'aaaa', 'sss58']})

df['last'] = df['strings'].str.split('_').str[-1]

df['last1'] = df['strings'].str.extract('(\d+)$')

print (df)
              strings   last last1
0      some_string_25     25    25
1  a_different_one_13     13    13
2   and_a_last_one_40     40    40
3                aaaa   aaaa   NaN
4               sss58  sss58    58
```

Comment: Very nice. What does the final `str` is doing before the `[-1]`? I get a KeyError if I don't include it, but haven't seen this syntax before.

Comment: @zabop - `str.split()` create lists and `str[-1]` select last one

Comment: Thanks! Why isn't simply `[-1]` enough to select the last element from the list, why do we need `str[-1]`?

Comment: (I get that simply `[-1]` is not enough becuase keyerror, but what does `str` do to make it work? or what is this method called, so I can google it)

Comment: @zabop - because if use `df['strings'].str.split('_')[-1]` it want return value if label is `-1`, if not exist errror. If use `print (df['strings'].str.split('_')[0])` it return `['some', 'string', '25']`, because label of first value is `0`

Comment: Thanks, got it now!

Comment: For better test `df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['some_string_25','a_different_one_13','and_a_last_one_40']}, index=[0,-1,-2])


print (df['strings'].str.split('_')[-1])
['a', 'different', 'one', '13']`

Comment: What would I have to do if not all the numbers are integers but some of them are float as well?

Comment: @corianne1234 - Do you think how change `df['last1'] = df['strings'].str.extract('(\d+)$')` ?

Comment: @corianne1234 - Can you test with real data - `df['last1'] = df['strings'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$')` ? I test with data `df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['some_string_2.5','a_different_one_13','and_a_last_one_40']})`

Comment: it gives me all nan values

Comment: @corianne1234 - How looks data for parsing? Can you edit question?

Answer (score 1):

Can do:

```
df['number']=df['strings'].apply(lambda row: row.split('_')[-1])
```

or:

```
df['number']=[row[-1] for row in df['strings'].str.split('_')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'strings':['some_string_25','a_different_one_13','and_a_last_one_40']})
df['number'] = df.strings.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
df
```